# can Ec2 instances from one account access ec2 instance of other account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

currently working with two environments/account.

Dev and staging

We are paling to spin up a new instance to install Jenkins for CI/CD in dev environment.

We are also wondering if we can use the same instance which is in dev as a CI/CD for staging account as well.

How will access work?
How can the CI/CD instance access the instances in stating for CI/CD?

Do we need to set up a cross-account role for this which allowed dev CI/CD to access the stating instances?
or
the private key is enough to have access to EC2 irrespective of account?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely enable this. Take a look at [VPC peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html).

This features enables 2 VPCs whether different account or different region, to connect to each other as there networks become connected via a tunnel between.

When you implement this the following factors are important:

- No cross over of CIDR ranges within VPCs
- The VPC peering connection must be added to the route table(s) in both VPCs allowing them to know how to connect to the other VPC.
- You will need to whitelist in security groups to allow access fro the instances that you want to be able to connect.

By doing this you also benefit from any network connections traversing the AWS backbone rather than across the public internet which will lead to improvements for security and performance.

Comment: what if the dev instance is in a default VPC in a separate account?

Comment: That is fine as long as there is no overlap of private CIDRs. If the prod account is not in the default VPC this should be the case.

Comment: Dev CICD instance is currently in default VPC. We are planning to have staging instances  in custom VPC

Comment: If they are spun up in a custom VPC then this will work :)

Comment: nice :) is there any other way to do it? 
When I was surfing through some article there is a way to have a cross-account role set up for the dev CICD ec2 which will be accessing staging account instances .

Comment: There are other ways such as enabling public access but they're not recommended. Could you perhaps let me know article and I'll try to double check what its recommending :)

Comment: article on cross-account assume roles.

Comment: I don't think its been added :(